# MSDN Crypto sample code not working / declaring Global Objects in form's constructor

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to use sample code from [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397867(v=vs.110).aspx) article.  The article does not offer an entire source code solution, but instead shows the individual methods code and other snippets as sections in the article.

In the article, under the topic **Declaring Global Objects** I have followed the instructions that say:  "*Add the following code to the Form's constructor.*" which I have done as follows:

```
public partial class MyCryptoTestForm : Form 
{
    public MyCryptoTestForm()
    {
        CspParameters cspp = new CspParameters();
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa;

        const string EncrFolder = @"c:\Encrypt\";
        const string DecrFolder = @"c:\Decrypt\";
        const string SrcFolder = @"c:\docs\";

        const string PubKeyFile = @"c:\encrypt\rsaPublicKey.txt";

        const string keyName = "Key01";

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The article also indicates a number of specific controls to add to the form and associated event code for these controls.  I have added all of the controls and their respective event code.

When I try to run the app (in debug) I'm getting the following errors:

> `The name cspp does not exist in the current context`.
>   `The name rsa does not exist in the current context`.

I have tried to copy all code from this article and follow the instructions exactly.

What am I doing wrong?

BTW -- I'm using:

- WIN7
- VS2015 Community Edition
- .NET Framework 4.5.2.1`

Comment: If you expect us to help you with your code, you need to include the code you wrote.

Comment: The problem is with BAD TEXT in the MSDN article.  All of the code is there.  I will refine the question text.  This should NOT be closed.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov -- OP has been edited

Comment: @DavidTansey Thank you for taking your time to refine my post - adding more information that I should have added to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the MSDN article you posted, I believe that there is a mis-quotation in the text where it says:

> Add the following code to the Form's constructor.

This statement is WRONG.  You do NOT want to add this code to the `constructor` of your form.  Doing so will cause the error you are seeing, because those declarations will be scoped local to the constructor method, not globally scoped to the Form class like you need it to be.

The code that follows that text contains a comment that states the correct thing to do:

```
// Declare CspParmeters and RsaCryptoServiceProvider
// objects with global scope of your Form class.
```

As an example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    // Declare CspParmeters and RsaCryptoServiceProvider
    // objects with global scope of your Form class.
    CspParameters cspp = new CspParameters();
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa;

    // Path variables for source, encryption, and
    // decryption folders. Must end with a backslash.
    const string EncrFolder = @"c:\Encrypt\";
    const string DecrFolder = @"c:\Decrypt\";
    const string SrcFolder = @"c:\docs\";

    // Public key file
    const string PubKeyFile = @"c:\encrypt\rsaPublicKey.txt";

    // Key container name for
    // private/public key value pair.
    const string keyName = "Key01";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // NOT HERE in the constructor, this scope will not work 

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for `pointing out the error in the article`. I followed your instructions and it worked.